# Approximation By Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

In Theorem 1.17 of (adult) Rudin, a measurable function $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ is approximated by a sequence $s_n = \varphi_n \circ f$, given by:

$$ \varphi_n(t) = \left\{\begin{array}[cc]
\,\lfloor t2^n \rfloor 2^{-n} & t \in [0,n)\\
n & t \in [n,\infty]\\
\end{array} \right.
$$ 
That $\varphi_n$ is measurable is clear. By definition of $\varphi_n$, $$\lfloor t2^n \rfloor \leq t2^n < \lceil t2^n \rceil \implies \lfloor t2^n \rfloor 2^{-n} = \varphi_n \leq t < \lceil t2^n \rceil 2^{-n}$$ for $t \in [0,n)$. The case $t\in [n,\infty]$ is trivial. Provided that  $0 \leq \varphi_1 \leq \varphi_2 \leq \cdots \leq t$, we have

$$\varphi_n(t) \in B(f(t),\epsilon) \implies \operatorname{d}(\varphi_n(t),f(t)) < \epsilon  \, \wedge \, \varphi_{n+1} \in [\varphi_n,t] \implies \operatorname{d}(\varphi_{n+1}(t),f(t)) < \epsilon$$
and the arguments for $[a,\infty] \ni t, [-\infty,a] \ni t$ are identical. WLOG considering only basic neighbourhoods of $t$, pointwise convergence follows.

But how do we establish $0 \leq \varphi_1 \leq \varphi_2 \leq \cdots \leq t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n$. If $t \geq n$, it is clear that $\phi_n(t)=n \leq t$. And for $t <n$ : let $k2^{-n}\leq t<(k+1)2^{-n}$ for some $k$. Then $\phi_n(t)=k2^{-n} \leq t$. So, $\phi_n(t)\leq t$ for any $n$. $t$ will lie in $[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$ for some $k$ which means $k$ lies in $[(2k)2^{-(n+1)},(2k+1)2^{-(n+1)})$ or $[(2k+1)2^{-(n+1)},(2k+2)2^{-(n+1)})$. In any case, $\phi_n(t) \leq \phi_{n+1}(t)$.

Note : In proving $\phi_n(t) \leq \phi_{n+1}(t)$, I did not take care to split the function for $t>n$ and $t\leq n$. But this will be quite straight forward.

Hope this helps