# Question on proof of approximation by simple functions from below

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently working through the book Real Analysis by G. B. Folland. On page 47 there is the well known approximation theorem of positive measurable functions from below by positive simple functions. Such a sequence can explicitely be constructed. For $n = 0,1,2,\dots$ and $0\leqslant k\leqslant 2^{2n}-1$, let $$E_n^k := f^{-1}((k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]) \qquad F_n := f^{-1}((2^n,\infty])$$ Then define $$\varphi_n := \sum_{k = 0}^{2^{2n}-1}k2^{-n}\chi_{E^k_n} + 2^n\chi_{F_n}$$ How can I show, that $\varphi_n \leqslant \varphi_{n+1} $?

I am aware of the fact, that there is a similar question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422195/approximation-by-simple-functions), but somehow I am not able to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have $ E^k_n = E^{2k}_{n+1} \cup E^{2k+1}_{n+1} $, where the union is disjoint. Now, prove that the inequality holds in every set $ E^k_n $.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $E_n^k$ together with $F_n$ are disjoint and cover $(0,\infty]$.

For a fixed $x>0$  will be element of exactly one of them.

If $x\in E_n^k$ or equivalently $\phi(x)=k2^{-n}$ we have: $$k2^{-n}<x\leq (k+1)2^{-n}$$  This can also be written as: $$2k2^{-n-1}<x\leq (2k+2)2^{-n-1}$$ This inequality tells us that: $$\phi_{n+1}(x)\in\{k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}\}=\{\phi_n(x),\phi_n(x)+2^{-n}\}$$

If $x\in F_n$ then $\phi_{n+1}(x)\geq2^n=\phi_n(x)$.